# Windows stuttering/lagging when dragging, scolling etc

Tags: lag, framerate

Windows on my laptop lags a lot. The framerate is feels like 3-4 fps.

The computer is a Lenovo P1 running latest Windows 10 May 2020 (2004)-version. All drivers are updated. I am using a docking station with three 27" external monitors, keeping the lid of the laptop shut.

If I restart, the problem is gone - usually until I've put the computer to sleep mode and brought it back.

Have [a look at this video for a demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1RCuA_Mi0w&feature=youtu.be&hd=1).

I've found [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/ea21z0/lenovo_resolves_thinkpad_p1_and_x1_extremes/), that possibly discusses the issue. Also [this entry](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/257428/laptop-1070-external-monitor-stutter/) on the NVidia forum seems to discuss the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Work-around

I found a work-around [mentioned by the user e.x.o](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/257428/laptop-1070-external-monitor-stutter/2323429/) which involved downloading DevManView, [a freeware alternative to Windows Device Manager](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) and running it via a batch file that disables and then re-enables the `Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630` device.

Sample batch script:

```
@echo off
echo *** Disbale/Enable Intel-GPU ***
devmanview.exe /disable_enable "Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630"
echo *** Done ***
close
```

PS: Make sure you've spelled the name of the device correctly. I did not at first.

From the discussions it seems this is a bug in the drivers of the graphic cards and/or some incompatibility between the drivers and Windows.

I have used this solution for 6 months now, and it's consistent.